# Svelte Simple Audio Player Not Updating

Tags: svelte, html5-audio

I'm building a simple audio player using Svelte. The selectedMusic variable update every time I click on the next and previous buttons. But the audio won't update. How to fix this?

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let src = [];
  let player;
  let active = 0;
  $: selectedMusic = src[active];
  let play = false;

  onMount(() => {
    player.volume = 0.5;
  });

  const next = () => {
    if (active < src.length - 1) {
      active++;
    } else {
      active = 0;
    }
    console.log(active);
    console.log(selectedMusic);
  };
  const previous = () => {
    if (active == 0) {
      active = src.length - 1;
    } else {
      active--;
    }
  };

  const togglePlay = () => {
    play ? player.pause() : player.play();
    play = !play;
  };
</script>

<audio bind:this={player} loop>
  <source src={selectedMusic} type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`.load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) method which can be called to make the change of the `src` have an effect. Either reactively every time `selectedMusic` changes or at the end of `previous()` and `next()`

```
    $: selectedMusic = src[active];
    $: reload(selectedMusic)

    const reload = () => {
        if(!player) return
        player.load()
        if(play) player.play()
    }
```

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2321a748873849a48d657ee16f0398bf?version=3.49.0)